# help removing extra body tags using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an application which is spitting out:
body {background: #FFF;}

over and over again. I am unable to fix the bug in the application. How can I use jquery to remove body {background: #FFF;} each time it occurs?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the source of the application which causes the bug?

Comment: I can't add any of the source from the application. What's happening is there is an application to add events to a page and for some reason every time you add an event, the body {background:#fff;} gets inserted in there and so there are multiple instances of this on the page that are overwriting anything I put in the css. For some reason nothing i do is working??

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit the css (I assume) but can you set an inline style on the body? This will overwrite the CSS applied style.

If not, here is the jQuery call to remove it on page load:

```
$(document).load(
    function()
    {
        $("body").css( "background-color", "transparent" );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to edit an style block declaration? I'm not sure jQuery really does much to help you in that case, but something like this might work:

```
for(int i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++) {
  var sheet = document.styleSheets[i],
      rules = sheet.cssRules ? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules;
  for(int j=0;j<rules.length;j++) {
    if(rules[j].toLower() == 'body {background: #fff;}')
      rules[j] = 'body {}';
  }
}
```

You might [check here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

> there are multiple instances of this
>   on the page that are overwriting
>   anything I put in the css.

Perhaps you are looking at it the wrong way... It can be overridden in the CSS, try putting this in the CSS file:

```
body{
   background:#0000ff !important;
}
```

Note the "!important" bit...